# "HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"?

Tags: ios, swift, http

I've done a http request with post parameters so many times, and I have now so many of them working just fine, I don't know why this one is not

this is the code

```
let url = NSURL(string: "bla bla lba")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
let body = "id=\(requestClient!.id!)"
print("body = \(body)")
request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task1 = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
```

the server expects a form parameter named `id` and its value is long

when I print the `id` from swift (as you can see the code), I get this

```
id=1453045943881.0
```

and i get this error

> HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

sounds like the server said the request is not correct, but where is the wrong?

this is the server

```
@Path("/checkForResponses")
    @POST
    public Response checkForResponeses (@FormParam("id") long id) {
```

Comment: Is your ID declared as Double? I would expect ID to be Integer. As you can see in your print, it has `.0` in the end, it might be problem. I guess the server expects ID to be integer.

Comment: What service is this? We'd need to know that the server expects. The error could easily be in the URL itself (the part elided as "bla bla bla"). Start with the service API docs for the specific request you're making and see where you've sent something it doesn't expect.

Comment: @SebastianOsiński I made the same mistake originally :D If you look at the code, the "id" is the requstClient and id separated by a "." (I have no idea if that's correct, but it's what the code is doing) It's not a float.

Comment: @SebastianOsiński the server expect long (and the server is java), the client swift declares the id as double.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm pretty sure this `"id=\(requestClient!.id!)"` means "Use string interpolation to print id property of requestClient variable". There is no   requestClient and id concatenation.

Comment: @RobNapier the server is java jersey, i have soo many request and all working , and all the same type and this request, i don't know why this request specially not working.

Comment: guys i can't make the id int, because it is a time stamp in the server, thus, it is long. and to receive long-value in my swift, i have to make it double.

Comment: i now put the code of the server, it is really easy

Comment: @sarah You can use `Int64` in Swift. It's the equivalent of Java's long

Comment: @SebastianOsiński i tried that before really, but i got exception on it. do you want to show u ? but that means to show you the exception from other code, which is the code that receives the id from the server, because in my logic, the server sends the id to the client, and then the client requests responses for that id each 5 minutes

Comment: @SebastianOsiński You're completely correct. I totally misread that. Thanks.

Comment: @sarah replace your `let body = "id=\(requestClient!.id!)"` with `let body = "id=\(requestClient!.id!)".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".0", withString: "")`. This will remove `.0` from id's string representation. It will show us if this causes the problem.

Comment: @SebastianOsiński yes that solved the problem, OMG so the doulbe was the problem. then i should make it now Int64. I will ask another question to say my exception when making it Int64 instaead of Double. you are genours thank you, please write an answer

Comment: @sarah Feel free to ask. I'll try to answer.

Comment: Seems like problem is not in your app. Are you sure that this server can apply such a long number? Try to use another but little number, something less then 2,147,483,647 , and please tell about results here.